# get specific string inside an html tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulSoup to scrape data here : https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html
And I would like to get the specific title of the book.

```
 <h3><a href="a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html" title="A Light in the Attic">A Light in the ...</a></h3>
```

I would like to get the contents inside the title tag which is "A Light in the Attic",

this is currently my code

```
for i in soup.find_all('h3'):
   titles = i.getText()
   print(titles)
```

The output is : A Light in the ...

I also tried this :

```
for i in soup.find_all('h3'):
   titles = i.find({'a' : 'title'})
   print(titles)
```

This is the output :  `<a href="a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html" title="A Light in the Attic">A Light in the ...</a>`

My desired output is to get the the title in the title tag which is : "A Light in the Attic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I got it. Here's the code

```
  for i in soup.find_all('h3'):
   titles = i.find('a')
   grabTitle = str(titles['title'])
   print(grabTitle)
```

output : A Light in the Attic